# SceneManager.LoadScene() is not working in the way i want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cs50, game-development

In my unity project i have 3 scenes.

1. Title
2. Play
3. Over

For achieving the flow Title -> Play -> Over. I had to start the game from Over scene. Over -> Title -> Play -> Over .. I don't want this. I want it to work when i start the game from Title scene. On doing so i am unable to change from Play -> Over.

for Title scene

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadSceneOnInput : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Submit") == 1) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Play");
        }
    }
}
```

for Over Scene

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameOverInput : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Submit") == 1) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Title");
        }
    }
}
```

Play's script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject floorPrefab;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;
    public GameObject ceilingPrefab;

    public GameObject characterController;

    public GameObject floorParent;
    public GameObject wallsParent;

    // allows us to see the maze generation from the scene view
    public bool generateRoof = true;

    // number of times we want to "dig" in our maze
    public int tilesToRemove = 50;

    public int mazeSize;

    // spawns at the end of the maze generation
    public GameObject pickup;

    // this will determine whether we've placed the character controller
    private bool characterPlaced = false;

    // 2D array representing the map
    private bool[,] mapData;

    // we use these to dig through our maze and to spawn the pickup at the end
    private int mazeX = 4, mazeY = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // initialize map 2D array
        mapData = GenerateMazeData();

        // create actual maze blocks from maze boolean data
        for (int z = 0; z < mazeSize; z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mazeSize; x++) {
                if (mapData[z, x]) {
                    CreateChildPrefab(wallPrefab, wallsParent, x, 1, z);
                    CreateChildPrefab(wallPrefab, wallsParent, x, 2, z);
                    CreateChildPrefab(wallPrefab, wallsParent, x, 3, z);
                } else if (!characterPlaced) {
                    
                    // place the character controller on the first empty wall we generate
                    characterController.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(
                        new Vector3(x, 1, z), Quaternion.identity
                    );

                    // flag as placed so we never consider placing again
                    characterPlaced = true;

                    CreateChildPrefab(floorPrefab, floorParent, x, 0, z);
                }

                //create floor and ceiling
                if(mapData[z, x]){
                    CreateChildPrefab(floorPrefab, floorParent, x, 0, z);
                }else{
                    if((z > 0 && z < mazeSize - 1) && (x > 0 && x < mazeSize - 1)){
                        if(!(Random.value > 0.8)){
                            CreateChildPrefab(floorPrefab, floorParent, x, 0, z);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (generateRoof) {
                    CreateChildPrefab(ceilingPrefab, wallsParent, x, 4, z);
                }
            }
        }

        // spawn the pickup at the end
        var myPickup = Instantiate(pickup, new Vector3(mazeX, 1, mazeY), Quaternion.identity);
        myPickup.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);

    }

     void Update() {
         if(characterController.transform.position.y < -5){
             SceneManager.LoadScene("Over");
         }
    }

    // generates the booleans determining the maze, which will be used to construct the cubes
    // actually making up the maze
    bool[,] GenerateMazeData() {
        bool[,] data = new bool[mazeSize, mazeSize];

        // initialize all walls to true
        for (int y = 0; y < mazeSize; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mazeSize; x++) {
                data[y, x] = true;
            }
        }

        // counter to ensure we consume a minimum number of tiles
        int tilesConsumed = 0;

        // iterate our random crawler, clearing out walls and straying from edges
        while (tilesConsumed < tilesToRemove) {
            
            // directions we will be moving along each axis; one must always be 0
            // to avoid diagonal lines
            int xDirection = 0, yDirection = 0;

            if (Random.value < 0.5) {
                xDirection = Random.value < 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
            } else {
                yDirection = Random.value < 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
            }

            // random number of spaces to move in this line
            int numSpacesMove = (int)(Random.Range(1, mazeSize - 1));

            // move the number of spaces we just calculated, clearing tiles along the way
            for (int i = 0; i < numSpacesMove; i++) {
                mazeX = Mathf.Clamp(mazeX + xDirection, 1, mazeSize - 2);
                mazeY = Mathf.Clamp(mazeY + yDirection, 1, mazeSize - 2);

                if (data[mazeY, mazeX]) {
                    data[mazeY, mazeX] = false;
                    tilesConsumed++;
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    // allow us to instantiate something and immediately make it the child of this game object's
    // transform, so we can containerize everything. also allows us to avoid writing Quaternion.
    // identity all over the place, since we never spawn anything with rotation
    void CreateChildPrefab(GameObject prefab, GameObject parent, int x, int y, int z) {
        var myPrefab = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
        myPrefab.transform.parent = parent.transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: You check that you join in your Submit condition in Over Scene?

Comment: “ there are no bugs in code as the game is running” bold claim as running doesn’t mean big free and you are here with an issue

Comment: `Although my logic is correct, it does not work as I would like` .. well apparently the logic is not correct then ;) `when player falls the scene does not change.` .. I see nothing in your code implementing such a condition so why should it?

Comment: 'when player falls the scene does not change' this was in Play's script.

Comment: When i run the Over scene first, the flow works fine. Over -> Title -> Play -> Over. For achieving this flow Title -> Play -> Over i always have to start the game from Over scene.